# Did the Ministry help the Dursleys to obtain guardianship over Harry

Tags: harry-potter

Based on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/103204/did-hogwarts-kidnap-harry-potter) question but going a bit back to the moment when Harry was adopted by the Dursleys.

Thinking about the situation after the murder of Lilly and James - the Dursleys are actually deep in trouble. They have to explain HOW did Harry end up with them on the same day when  his parents were killed.

Did the Ministry intervene in this case to cover up the whole story?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no hint in the novels that there was anything unusual about the Dursley's adoption of Harry. I certainly don't see any reason to think there would be any suspicion laid on them related to the murders on James and Lily, just because Harry ended up with them, as there's no evidence whatsoever that they were involved. And, as Petunia Dursley was Harry's next of kin, it would have been almost expected (thought not required) of the Dursley's to take him in.

Imagine if the Potters had died of completely natural causes -- their house burned down, for example. If you -- a friend of theirs -- happened to discover them dead and their infant son alive, your first action would probably be to *take him somewhere* where he can be cared for, away from the drama of his parent death. Assuming you didn't try to hide the actual death of his parents, it wouldn't be at all unusual to tell the authorities,

> We found them like this officer; they have a baby son, we took him to his aunt's house so she could take care of him for now.

Depending on what else you did at the "scene", the authorities might be a bit suspicious of *you*, which in this case would mean Hagrid. But there wouldn't be any reason for them to suspect The Dursleys of anything unusual, just because Hagrid happened to take the baby there.

It was well known in the wizarding community what happened to the Potters (mostly -- of course most people wrongly blamed Sirius instead of Peter). And the muggle community probably knew little of what happened to the Potters other than they died in a tragic accident of some sort.

There wouldn't have been any need for the Ministry to get involved, and the muggle Child Protective Service (not sure what the UK equivalent is here) would have *expected* Aunt Petunia to step in and take Harry.

Comment: Actually Dumbledore brought Harry to the Dursleys in the same night where the Potters were murdered. So from the murder investigation point of view they ARE involved or at least have to provide some reasonable explanation.

Comment: I think you missed the OP's point of concern. The problem is that Hagrid took Harry away from the site, either out of the arms of the first responders or before the first responders even got there, and therefore before the muggle authorities had a chance to establish and notify his next-of-kin. The issue isn't whether Harry belongs with the Durleys (from a legal perspective, anyway), but how he got there without intervention by the authorities

Comment: @JasonBaker that is true. Again, though, "take the baby to a relative ASAP" seemed like the expected behavior for anyone who found him...

Comment: @vap78 explanation of what? "Some guy showed up at our house with my nephew and told me to watch him, so I did."

Comment: @vap78 The Dursleys were most likely never involved in any murder investigation. The Muggle police probably weren't, either. There's no reason to believe the story the Dursleys had told Harry his whole life about a car crash wasn't the official story created by someone infiltrated in the police force faking case files and making it look like there had been an accident. Only the wizarding community knew it was murder, and they all knew perfectly well who was the murderer.

Comment: @Jason: Would there even have been any first responders?  The Fidelius charm was presumably still in effect, even if the house didn't have any other anti-Muggle defensive measures.  The Ministry would eventually have to give Harry a Muggle identity, but there wouldn't be any rush - just so long as he was in the files by the time he had to go to school.

Answer (score 8):

## Custody of Harry Potter

When it comes to orphan kids of wizards we see three options used by Ministry of Magic:

**1. Allow kids to go to Muggle Orphanage:**

Voldemort had to live in an Muggle Orphanage.

> “You live in a Muggle orphanage during the holidays, I believe?” said Dippet curiously.
>
> “Yes, sir,” said Riddle, reddening slightly.
>
> “You are Muggle-born?”
>
> “Half-blood, sir,” said Riddle. “Muggle father, witch mother.”
>
> “And are both your parents —?”
>
> “My mother died just after I was born, sir. They told me at the orphanage she lived just long enough to name me — Tom after my father, Marvolo after my grandfather.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 13, The Very Secret Diary*</sup></sub>

**2. Let the kid stay with a relative:**

Harry had to stay with Dursleys (his uncle and aunt) and Neville Longbottom had to stay with his grandmother.

> “Yes,” said Professor McGonagall. “And I don’t suppose you’re going to tell me why you’re here, of all places?”
>
> “I’ve come to bring Harry to his aunt and uncle. They’re the only family he has left now.”
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter 1, The Boy Who Lived</sup></sub>

**3. Foster Care:**

> Dumbledore stared for a moment at the sunlit grounds outside the window, then looked back at Harry and said, “Five years ago you arrived at Hogwarts, Harry, safe and whole, as I had planned and intended. Well - not quite whole. You had suffered. I knew you would when I left you on your aunt and uncle’s doorstep. I knew I was condemning you to ten dark and difficult years.”
>
> He paused. Harry said nothing.
>
> “You might ask - and with good reason - why it had to be so. Why could some wizarding family not have taken you in? Many would have done so more than gladly, would have been honored and delighted to raise you as a son.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 37, The Lost Prophecy</sup></sub>

Dursleys knew that Potters were wizards. Petunia Dursley grew up with Lily Potter.

> "She confessed the truth during a tear-stained date, in Vernon's dark car as they sat overlooking the chip shop where Vernon had just bought them a post-cinema snack. Vernon, as Petunia had expected, was deeply shocked; however, he told Petunia solemnly that he would never hold it against her that she had a freak for a sister"
>
> The first meeting between Lily, her boyfriend James Potter, and the engaged couple, went badly, and the relationship nose-dived from there. James was amused by Vernon, and made the mistake of showing it. Vernon tried to patronise James, asking what car he drove. James described his racing broom. Vernon supposed out loud that wizards had to live on unemployment benefit.
>
> **[Potters meeting Dursleys](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Vernon_%26_Petunia_Dursley)**

So it made sense for Harry to grow up with his relatives instead of a wizarding family he did not know.

## Regarding the Murder

James and Lily Potter were murdered magically using the killing curse (Avada Kedavra).

> Lily, take Harry and go! It’s him! Go! Run! I’ll hold him off!”
>
> Hold him off, without a wand in his hand? . . . . He laughed before casting the curse. . .
>
> “Avada Kedavra!”
>
> “Stand aside. Stand aside, girl!”
>
> He could have forced her away from the crib, but it seemed more prudent to finish them all. . . .
>
> The green light flashed around the room and she dropped like her husband.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 17, Bathilda's Secret</sup></sub>

The Ministry can distinguish between magical and normal killing.

> The Muggle authorities were perplexed. As far as I am aware, they do not know to this day how the Riddles died, for the Avada Kedavra curse does not usually leave any sign of damage... The exception sits before me,” Dumbledore added, with a nod to Harry’s scar. “The Ministry, on the other hand, knew at once that this was a wizard’s murder.
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 17, A Sluggish Memory</sup></sub>

Since both Vernon & Petunia Dursley were muggles, they cannot be blamed for murder committed by a wizard using magic.

All ministry had to do was to charm couple of Police officers to write false report of accidental (or unexplained) deaths of James and Lily Potter.

Comment: Didn't the street get blown up by Pettigrew in an attempt to frame Sirius? Or was that elsewhere?

Comment: @CarlSixsmith That was when Peter succeeded hunting Sirius (in truth the other way around of course, when Sirius caught up with Peter). We don't know where that was, nor how long it actually took.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the Muggle police might not be able to actually class it as a murder.

Answer (score 0):

Wizards have no legal documents in the muggle world. They are not registered under a census, will not show up on any lists, etc. So Lily and James' deaths were insignificant in the Muggle world. Harry was also non-existent in Muggle records until his parents died.

I'm assuming Dumbledore/Law Enforcement stepped in to create an identity for Harry so that he would be adopted easily by the Dursleys. Even a Confundus Charm would do. After all, this is Harry Potter we are talking about. Even the Minister would have fallen over himself to keep Harry safe(though Dumbledore would have had the last say)

Or since Harry was barely a year old, the Dursleys may have registered him as a newly adopted baby. Harry never grew to be of age in the Muggle world, so the legality of his documents(if any) never came into question.

Comment: Lilly Potter is muggle born. She surely has legal documents. Also as confirmed by JKR - many wizard kids go to normal muggle schools for basic education. So they have to be registered as any other kid i.e. the parents have to be too.

Comment: I forgot about Lily there for a second. Yes, JKR did say that some families send their children to Muggle school. I always assumed it was a harmless charm that made the Muggles remember something else very important that they had to do, everytime they wanted to check the kid's certificates. Seems like wizards wouldn't want to go to the trouble getting Muggle documents for a kid who is anyway going to Hogwarts at eleven.